# Query em uma string SQL em C#

Tags: sql, string, query

Estou fazendo uma query no banco de dados via string `sql.append`, na chamada do método tenho dois parâmetros, duas strings estas recebem um `textbox` digitados pelo usuário e fazem a verificação no banco de dados.

Como faço a concatenação correta? Abaixo está o `insert` que fiz e está funcionando. E no caso da outra, como faço?

**Código**

```
    sql.Append("Insert into AppSignin(UserName, FirstName, LastName, Email, Password) Values ('");
    sql.Append(ClearText(userName));
    sql.Append("','");
    sql.Append(ClearText(firstName));
    sql.Append("','");
    sql.Append(ClearText(lastName));
    sql.Append("','");
    sql.Append(ClearText(Email));
    sql.Append("','");   
    sql.Append(ClearText(Password));
    sql.Append("')'");
```

E abaixo a query que devo fazer:

```
sql.Append("Select Count(*) as Qtd From AppUser Where UserName = UserName OR Email = Email)
```

Baseado no modelo acima como devo fazer esta?

As querys foram tratadas através do método `ClearText`. Mas realmente, é muito mais fácil.
 Neste caso não posso usar `sqlcommand` pois estou usando OleDB e a ConnectionString dentro de um arquivo UDL.

Segue abaixo o código completo consegui fazer a query:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string usuario = TextBox1.Text;
    string nome = TextBox2.Text;
    string sobrenome = TextBox3.Text;
    string email = TextBox4.Text;
    string senha = TextBox5.Text;

    try
    {
        string sErr = ValidateFields();
        if (sErr.Length == 0)
        {
            SetUser(usuario, nome, sobrenome, email, senha);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write(sErr.ToString());  
        }

        Label6.Text = "Dados cadastrados com Sucesso";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

public void SetUser(string userName, string firstName, string lastName, string Email, string Password)
{
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
    DbCommand cmd = factory.CreateCommand();
    DbConnection cn = factory.CreateConnection();
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

    cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];

    sql.Append("Insert into AppSignin(UserName, FirstName, LastName, Email, Password) Values ('");
    sql.Append(ClearText(userName));
    sql.Append("','");
    sql.Append(ClearText(firstName));
    sql.Append("','");
    sql.Append(ClearText(lastName));
    sql.Append("','");
    sql.Append(ClearText(Email));
    sql.Append("','");   
    sql.Append(ClearText(Password));
    sql.Append("')");

    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = sql.ToString();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cn.Close();
}

private string ValidateFields()
{
    StringBuilder sErr = new StringBuilder();
    string usuario = TextBox1.Text;
    string nome = TextBox2.Text;
    string sobrenome = TextBox3.Text;
    string email = TextBox4.Text;
    string senha = TextBox5.Text;

    if (TextBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        Label6.Text = "Campo Usuario Obrigatório!";
    }
    if (TextBox4.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        Label6.Text = "Campo Email Obrigatório!";
    }

    if (sErr.Length == 0)
    {
        if (HasAppUser(usuario, email) || HasAppSignin(usuario, email))
        {
            Label6.Text = " Usuário ou Email já cadastrado ";
        }
    }

    return sErr.ToString();  
}


private string ClearText(string value)
{
    value = value.Replace("'", "`");
    value = value.Replace("<", "");
    return value;
}

private bool HasAppUser(string userName, string Email)
{
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
    DbCommand cmd = factory.CreateCommand();
    DbConnection cn = factory.CreateConnection();
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

    cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];

    sql.Append("Select Count(*) as Qtd From AppUser Where UserName = ? OR Email = ?");

    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = sql.ToString();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    DbParameter par = factory.CreateParameter();
    par.DbType = DbType.String;
    par.ParameterName = "?";
    par.Value = userName;

    DbParameter par2 = factory.CreateParameter();
    par2.DbType = DbType.String;
    par2.ParameterName = "?";
    par2.Value = Email;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(par);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(par2);

    cn.Open();
    int nQtd = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    cn.Close();

    return (nQtd > 0);
}

private bool HasAppSignin(string userName, string Email)
{
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
    DbCommand cmd = factory.CreateCommand();
    DbConnection cn = factory.CreateConnection();
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

    cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];

    sql.Append("Select Count(*) as Qtd From AppSignin Where UserName = ? OR Email = ?");

    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = sql.ToString();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    DbParameter par = factory.CreateParameter();
    par.DbType = DbType.String;
    par.ParameterName = "?";
    par.Value = userName;

    DbParameter par2 = factory.CreateParameter();
    par2.DbType = DbType.String;
    par2.ParameterName = "?";
    par2.Value = Email;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(par);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(par2);

    cn.Open();
    int nQtd = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    cn.Close();

    return (nQtd > 0);
}
}
```

Comment: Na verdade você pode sim. Pode por favor colocar seu código completo para que possamos aprimorar a resposta?

Answer (score 7):

Isto está terrivelmente errado. O certo é você parametrizar sua `query` para evitar *SQL Injection*:

```
sql.Append("Insert into AppSignin(UserName, FirstName, LastName, Email, Password) Values (:UserName, :FirstName, :LastName, :Email, :Password)");
var sqlCommand = new DbCommand(sql, connection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new DbParameter { ParameterName = "UserName", Value = valorUserName});
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new DbParameter { ParameterName = "FirstName", Value = valorFirstName});
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new DbParameter { ParameterName = "LastName", Value = valorLastName});
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new DbParameter { ParameterName = "Email", Value = valorEmail});
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new DbParameter { ParameterName = "Password", Value = valorPassword});
```

Portanto, a segunda fica:

```
sql.Append("Select Count(*) as Qtd From AppUser Where UserName = :UserName OR Email = :Email");
var sqlCommand = new DbCommand(sql, connection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new DbParameter { ParameterName = "UserName", Value = valorUserName});
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new DbParameter { ParameterName = "Email", Value = valorEmail});
```

Answer (score 2):

Também é legal usar parametros aos seu método **SqlCommand()**. Exemplo:

```
public void SeuMetodo()
{
string commandText = "Insert into AppSignin(UserName) values ('@userNameParameter')";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

        string userName = "Franscisco";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userNameParameter", userName);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Matheus pelas dicas, mas as querys foram tratadas através de um método (ClearText). mas realmente : é muito mais fácil, neste caso não posso usar sql command pois estou usando OleDB e a ConnectionString dentro de um arquivo UDL.... então não posso usar o sqlCommand.

Comment: Não tem por onde @Thiago, rs. Mas tenho uma pergunta, o OleDB não tem o "OleDBCommand"? E no OleDBCommand não tem a extensão de "Parameters"?

Comment: Tem sim Matheus, cara você me ajudou muito obrigado! Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Como o pessoal falou a forma correta é usando Command.
Mas o q vc quer fazer, pode ficar mais fácil usando string.format.

**Segue o exemplo:**

```
string email, userName;
email = "teste@gmail.com";
userName = "xpto";
sql.Append(string.Format("Select Count(*) as Qtd From AppUser Where UserName = {0} OR Email = {1})", ClearText(userName), ClearText(email)));
```